# How to make a histogram in ipython notebook using ggplot2 (for python)

Tags: python, ggplot2, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-ggplot

I'm trying to make a histogram of a simple list of numbers in python using [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) and [ggplot for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot). Using pylab, it's easy enough, but I cannot get ggplot to work.

I'm using this code (based on the diamond histogram example, which does work for me):

```
from ggplot import *
a = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]
p = ggplot(aes(x='carat'), data=a)
p + geom_hist() + ggtitle("Histogram of Diamond Carats") + labs("Carats", "Freq")
```

Using ipython & pylab, I can make a histogram with just `hist(a)` and it displays. How do I make a histogram come up using ggplot?

Comment: Do you want ggplot because of the style or is there another reason. If the former is the case, you can try mpltools, a matplotlib extension which can mimic the style of ggplot (see http://tonysyu.github.io/mpltools/auto_examples/style/plot_ggplot.html)

Comment: I mostly want to use ggplot because it seems interesting.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to make a histogram of the numbers in your vector 'a', there are a couple of problems.

First, ggplot accepts data in the form of a pandas Dataframe, so you need to build that first.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
```

Second, the geom is `geom_histogram()` not `geom_hist()`. And finally, it looks like you're throwing in code from one of the example plots of the diamond data. You don't need that, so I've removed it.

```
from ggplot import *
p = ggplot(aes(x='a'), data=df)
p + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Did you add

`%matplotlib inline`

as first command in your notebook?